# Can't connect Mongoose to MongoDB with authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a user with `readwrite` role for MongoDB database `myDatabase`.

After starting MongoDB server with `--auth`, in Mongo shell:

```
mongo -u userName -p userPassword --authenticationDatabase myDatabase
```

Connects properly and can read/write myDatabase

In mongoose tried to connect to MongoDB using

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDatabase', {user:'userName', password:'userPassword'});
```

Also

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDatabase', {user:'userName', password:'userPassword', {auth: {authdb:'myDatabase'}});
```

Able to connect to myDatabase but get authorization error when read/write

> MongoError: not authorized for query on myDatabase.myCollection

How can I fix this?

Comment: What authenticationDatabase are you connecting through mongo Shell?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to try the following:

1) Connect with string URI format https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

2) Which version of mongoose are you using? According to the docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html you should provide 'pass' property but you are passing it as 'password'.

Comment: I switched to a more recent version of Mongoose and changed the property to pass instead of password and it is now working as expected.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the auth database. Your second attempt was almost correct but instead of `authdb` you should use `authSource` options. In your case it should be

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDatabase', {user:'userName', password:'userPassword', {auth: {authSource:'myDatabase'}});
```